# How to join multiple objects?

Tags: objects

I have created a bunny rabbit using a path beveled into a circle shape which I have resized accordingly for each different part of the rabbit. A picture below will show you what I mean.

My question is: How can I join all of these shapes into a single entity so that the object moves as an entire unit when I select any single part of its body?

I have tried to select all the items and use Ctrl+J, but it collapses my rabbit, effectively ruining it. The second picture depicts what happens to my rabbit after I attempt to use Ctrl+J on all its pieces. Mind you, each piece of the rabbit is just a copied sphere of the original, resized and recolored. After Ctrl+J'ing, it seems to revert to the original object shape.

How can I properly join all my rabbit's pieces intact?

[image: o]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to add a fixed constraint to the object.  Simply click 2 objects then add a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend applying the scale/rotation of each object before joining. This may solve your problem.

If that doesn't work, any modifiers applied to a single object may lose their effect upon joining the objects, or their effect may be distributed to other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a video that may help you join all of your shapes into a single entity so that the object moves as an entire unit when you select any single part of its body.  It's shows you how to do this for Blender 2.7x but will also work in Blender 2.8x it will also get rid of the extra geometry.

https://youtu.be/kf16s5MPBLg

Also

https://youtu.be/YLoKjR8H-JQ

Video that shows this in Blender 2.8x

https://youtu.be/Eb-DO6E0tnY

Answer (score 0):

go to add modifiers, add a boolean modifier, change from difference to union and use the dropper to select the item and click apply, copy the modifier to add more objects and make sure you delete the duplicate object it creates behind the merged object

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't meet you're rule for "the object moves as an entire unit when I select any single part of its body" but maybe it's helpful.

Another option would be to parent all the objects to an Empty. Then when you manipulate the Empty, all the parts follow, and each object remains editable and transformable.